# swift: adding uistackView with UITextField of same height

Tags: swift, layout

I have a vertical StackView with Distribution "Equal Spacing"
containing horizontal StackViews each containing a Switch and a label except the last one, which contains a Switch and a TextField.
Now, when the Switch of that last one is turned on, I want to add an additional horizontal StackView to the vertical one which looks like the last one:

```
@IBAction func onValueChange(_ sender: UISwitch) {
    let parent = sender.superView as! UIStackView
    let pparent = parent.superView as! UIStackView
    let textField = parent.arragedSubviews[1] as TextField

    let row = UIStackView
    row.axis = UILayoutConstraintAxis.horizontal
    row.spacing = 30
    let swtch = UISwitch()
    swtch.isOn = false
    let input = UITextField()
    input.borderStyle = textField.borderStyle
    row.addArrangedSubView(swtch)
    row.addArrangedSubView(input)
    pparent.addArrangedSubView(row)
}
```

it works quite well, except the new row is smaller in height and therefore the textfield is also smaller in height, which looks stupid. I didn't put any restraints on the horizontal StackViews. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Use `.fillEqually` instead of `.equalSpacing` to make sure that the rows in the `stackView` would equal in height.